# keyError in pandas on selecting multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a weird error when selecting multiple columns in pandas dataframe. Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./Dataset/train.csv", engine='python')
df['eviv1', 'v2a1']
```

I get this error message: `KeyError: ('eviv1', 'v2a1')`
but I don't get an error message when running

```py
df['eviv1']
```

```py
df[v2a1]
```

separately.
PS: I am using python 3 and Jupyter Notebook with pandas version 0.23.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column names (which are strings) cannot be sliced in the manner you tried.  Please try this,

```py
df[['eviv1', 'v2a1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, inner brackets are used to select column names and outer brackets are used to select data.
Thus, we use 2 sets of square brackets:

```py
df[['eviv1', 'v2a1']]
```